# How to start upload file in Angular JS?

Tags: angularjs

I use Angular JS [library](https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload/wiki/Module-API) `angular-file-upload`.
I moved init `FileUploader` code from controller to `factory` method:

```
.factory('UploadFilesHash', ['FileUploader', function (FileUploader) {

            var uploader;

            return {

                uploadInit: function (data){
                    uploader = new FileUploader({
                        url: '/upload/',
                        formData: data,
                        alias: 'files',
                        autoUpload: true
                    });

                    // FILTERS
                    uploader.filters.push({
                        name: 'imageFilter',
                        fn: function (item /*{File|FileLikeObject}*/, options) {
                            var type = '|' + item.type.slice(item.type.lastIndexOf('/') + 1) + '|';
                            return '|jpg|png|jpeg|bmp|gif|'.indexOf(type) !== -1;
                        }
                    });

                    // CALLBACKS
                    uploader.onWhenAddingFileFailed = function (item /*{File|FileLikeObject}*/, filter, options) {
                        //console.info('onWhenAddingFileFailed', item, filter, options);
                    };

});
}
```

So, in controller I do inject this factory and call init function:

**Controller:**

```
$scope.startFromView = function (){
    UploadFilesHash.uploadInit(data);
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<span ng-click="startFromView()">
<input type="file" nv-file-select="" uploader="uploader" multiple  />
</span>
```

So, problem is that I call function `startFromView()` then there is no file upload. Earlier this code was at controller and all work.

Comment: the `var uploader` in your factory doesn't correspond to the `$scope.uploader` that you are supplying in the input field.

Comment: Okay, I need to return  variable `uploader` from `UploadFilesHash` for `$scope.uploader`?

Comment: I tried, I get error: `"Uploader" must be an instance of FileUploader`